# Integer in a Double field

Tags: integer, double, type-conversion

Is it completely safe to use an integer in a field of double? Or any problem can arise during casting( could the value get changed or other hassles?)
I would like to know which type of problem can arise when i use a data type under a field of a bigger data type?

Comment: Which language are you talking about? The *exact* details matter here. Giving a code example of what you mean would make it easier to help you.

Comment: let's suppose for java. Though I am talking in general here. As I am researching on which data conversions could trigger a security concern.

Comment: Again, there's no "in general" here. What kind of integer are you talking about? `long` is an integer type, but `long` to `double` can lose information... whereas `int` to `double` can't.

Comment: "int to double can't" - is it because double has a larger field?
(I am currently working on java code. Although I would like to understand the core idea. What issues there could cause a problem? )

Comment: It's because every 32-bit integer can be exactly represented in an IEEE-754 64-bit binary floating point number.

Comment: Java 'int' to 'double' can't overflow because Java uses 32 bit binary integers for `int` and IEEE-754 64-bit binary floating point for `double`. Different choices for either type might give a different answer. It really is language dependent, and for some languages implementation dependent.